# How to make Entity Framework Core DbSet Take and Skip take long type, not int (I have more than 4 billion rows)

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How to make Entity Framework Core `DbSet` `Take` and `Skip` methods use `long` type, not `int`? (I have a table with more than 4 billion rows; it contains posts' likes relations).

Comment: Add a where clause so you do not need to browse the entire table?

Comment: I just want to know to handle the weirdest case scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with current EF Core. But you can use extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (note that I'm one of the creators) which have appropriate extensions for that:

```cs
long skip = ...
long take = ...

var query = context.SomeBig
   .Skip(() => skip)
   .Take(() => take)
   .ToLinqToDB()
   .ToList();
```

Anyway such big `Skip` is not performant in real world scenarios and you have to use more advanced techniques for pagination. One of them: remembering previous ID

**First page:**

```cs
var pageResult = context.SomeBig
   .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
   .Take(pageSize)
   .ToList();

var lastId = pageResult.Last().Id;
```

**Next page:**

```cs
var pageResult = context.SomeBig
   .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
   .Where(x => x.Id > lastId)
   .Take(pageSize)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: *such big Skip is not performant in real world scenarios* -- Might be something to convey in LinqToDb by not supporting it. Something to consider.

Comment: @GertArnold, Actually we support not just `long` skip but any expression in Skip, so theoretically you can create [such query](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14104)

Comment: Yeah, alright, makes sense. Would take too much validation code to keep users from shooting themselves in the foot.